# Make error when trying to build OpenShadingLanguage on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, build, include, makefile

I have all dependencies set up, as far as I'm aware, ccmake shows everything has been found. However, when I run make, I get the following output:

```
shanesimmsart@shanesimmsart-pc:~/OpenShadingLanguage/build$ make
[  1%] Building CXX object src/liboslcomp/CMakeFiles/oslcomp.dir/ast.cpp.o
In file included from /home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/include/osl_pvt.h:31:0,
                 from /home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/liboslcomp/ast.cpp:35:
/home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/include/OSL/oslconfig.h:109:13: error: ‘OIIO::string_view’ has not been declared
 using OIIO::string_view;
             ^
In file included from /home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/liboslcomp/ast.cpp:35:0:
/home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/include/osl_pvt.h:54:1: error: ‘string_view’ does not name a type
 string_view shadertypename (ShaderType s);
 ^
/home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/include/osl_pvt.h:58:34: error: ‘string_view’ was not declared in this scope
 ShaderType shadertype_from_name (string_view name);
                                  ^
/home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/include/osl_pvt.h:76:32: error: ‘string_view’ was not declared in this scope
 ShaderUse shaderuse_from_name (string_view name);
                                ^
In file included from /home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/liboslcomp/oslcomp_pvt.h:36:0,
                 from /home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/liboslcomp/ast.cpp:36:
/home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/include/OSL/oslcomp.h:52:19: error: ‘string_view’ has not been declared
     bool compile (string_view filename,
                   ^
/home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/include/OSL/oslcomp.h:54:19: error: ‘string_view’ has not been declared
                   string_view stdoslpath = string_view());
                   ^
/home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/include/OSL/oslcomp.h:59:26: error: ‘string_view’ has not been declared
     bool compile_buffer (string_view sourcecode, std::string &osobuffer,
                          ^
/home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/include/OSL/oslcomp.h:61:26: error: ‘string_view’ has not been declared
                          string_view stdoslpath = string_view());
                          ^
/home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/include/OSL/oslcomp.h:65:5: error: ‘string_view’ does not name a type
     string_view output_filename () const;
     ^
/home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/include/OSL/oslcomp.h:54:56: error: ‘string_view’ was not declared in this scope
                   string_view stdoslpath = string_view());
                                                        ^
/home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/include/OSL/oslcomp.h:61:63: error: ‘string_view’ was not declared in this scope
                          string_view stdoslpath = string_view());
                                                               ^
In file included from /home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/liboslcomp/oslcomp_pvt.h:37:0,
                 from /home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/liboslcomp/ast.cpp:36:
/home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/liboslcomp/ast.h:354:5: error: ‘string_view’ does not name a type
     string_view shadertypename () const;
     ^
In file included from /home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/liboslcomp/ast.cpp:36:0:
/home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/liboslcomp/oslcomp_pvt.h:69:19: error: ‘string_view’ has not been declared
     bool compile (string_view filename,
                   ^
/home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/liboslcomp/oslcomp_pvt.h:71:19: error: ‘string_view’ has not been declared
                   string_view stdoslpath);
                   ^
/home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/liboslcomp/oslcomp_pvt.h:73:26: error: ‘string_view’ has not been declared
     bool compile_buffer (string_view sourcecode,
                          ^
/home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/liboslcomp/oslcomp_pvt.h:76:26: error: ‘string_view’ has not been declared
                          string_view stdoslpath);
                          ^
/home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/liboslcomp/oslcomp_pvt.h:249:5: error: ‘string_view’ does not name a type
     string_view output_filename () const { return m_output_filename; }
     ^
/home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/liboslcomp/ast.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void OSL::pvt::ASTshader_declaration::print(std::ostream&, int) const’:
/home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/liboslcomp/ast.cpp:195:59: error: ‘shadertypename’ was not declared in this scope
     out << "(" << nodetypename() << " " << shadertypename()
                                                           ^
/home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/liboslcomp/ast.cpp: At global scope:
/home/shanesimmsart/OpenShadingLanguage/src/liboslcomp/ast.cpp:204:1: error: ‘string_view’ does not name a type
 string_view
 ^
make[2]: *** [src/liboslcomp/CMakeFiles/oslcomp.dir/ast.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/liboslcomp/CMakeFiles/oslcomp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This appears to be an issue with string_view.h, included from OpenImageIO, however when I look in /usr/include/OpenImageIO/, string_view.h is right there. As far as I can tell, OIIO is up to date with version 1.5, so I can't imagine it's a version issue either, although I'm not ruling that out.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's no error message stating not that the file is not found, so observing that it's "right there" isn't germane: it's not that the compiler can't find it.  If indeed the missing declarations can be found in `string_view.h` then either it's not being included properly where it needs to be, or else there's something else (`#ifdef`?) which is keeping the needed declarations from being visible to the compiler.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.

I've tried actually going into oslconfig.h and string_view.h and playing around with the includes, with no luck, although it seems silly that I should be adjusting things like this. Not sure what I should be changing here.

Comment: You should find a mailing list or forum for support of this software, and ask them about it.